# How to calculate the volume of a point set with parameters go over the Haar distribution?

Tags: haar-distribution

Speically, how to calculate the volume of the set $\{(|\langle\psi|M_1|\psi\rangle|^2,...,|\langle\psi|M_s|\psi\rangle|^2)|\rho \in \mathbb{H}^n\}$ in the space $\mathbb{R}^{s}$, in which $\mathbb{H}^n$ is the set of all $n$-qubit pure states, and $\{M_i\}$ is a set of $s$ Hermitian matrices?

I think it might be the integration
\begin{align}
  &\int_{\text{the set}} d|\langle\psi|M_1|\psi\rangle|^2...d|\langle\psi|M_s|\psi\rangle|^2,\\
  =&\int_{\mathbb{H}^n} F(\psi,M_1,...,M_s) d\psi,
\end{align}
but I really don't know what's the function $F$ here.